# Js code isn't working it exits with code=1

Tags: javascript, node.js

It says that it can't find prompt-sync and exits with code=1

```
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')();

var fname = prompt("Enter your first name : ");
var lname = prompt("Enter your last name : ");

console.log("Your full name is : ",fname + " " + lname);
```

I tried to changeing

```
console.log("Your full name is : ",fname,lname);
```

to

```
console.log("Your full name is : ",fname + " " + lname);
```

Comment: Have you installed the `prompt-sync` library with `npm`?

Comment: Why do you think changing the `console.log` line will make any difference? The error happens on the `require` call, doesn't it?

Comment: @Barmar yes i installed it

Comment: @Barmar I don't really know where is the problem I just started learning js, i looked up the problem and tried to fix it

Answer (score 0):

#### You can replicate the error with just this:

```
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')();
```

This means that the problem occurs when trying to find "prompt-sync".

#### The documentation of prompt-sync is not ideal

I've had a quick look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt-sync

It mentions the optional installation of a history module, but does not mention the main installation. This may be why it is not working for you.

#### How to fix

On the system command line (Windows terminal or Mac terminal), with the working directory set to the directory of your project, type:

```
npm install prompt-sync
```

If that command gives an error, first install `npm` itself.

Once prompt-sync is installed, you should be able to run your code.